# LIMIT the number of rows in GROUP BY and GROUP_CONCAT with ORDER

Tags: mysql, query, group-by, group-concatenation

In this [sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=f2bebbf2b0f85a4c32703c97660004fe),

```
CREATE TABLE t1
(
id int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
val int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
rank mediumint(7) unsigned,
INDEX(id),
INDEX(rank),
PRIMARY KEY(id,val)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;

INSERT INTO t1 (id,val,rank) VALUES (1,2,2), (1,1,1), (1,9,1), (1,5,23), 
(1,3,2), (2,2,1), (2,9,8), (2,5,0);

SELECT id,GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(val,'|',rank) ORDER BY rank DESC SEPARATOR ',') 
FROM t1 GROUP BY id;
```

How can I LIMIT the number of rows returned by `GROUP_BY`?

My problem is that `ORDER` within `GROUP_BY` should be identical to `ORDER` within  `GROUP_CONCAT`.

For example, if using `LIMIT 3`, the output should be

```
id  GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(val,'|',rank) ORDER BY rank DESC SEPARATOR ',')
1   5|23,3|2,2|2
2   9|8,2|1,5|0
```

Comment: What is the purpose of `id`?  Where does it come from?

Comment: I think there is a feature request on `GROUP_CONCAT`.

Comment: @RickJames this is so silly of me. You're absolutely right. GROUP_CONCAT` has `LIMIT` feature itself. I was re-inventing the wheel :) You're a life saver!

Comment: MariaDB 10.3 has `GROUP_CONCAT(... LIMIT )`, but I don't think MySQL does.

Comment: @RickJames I use MariaDB. The sample SQLFiddle is MariaDB 10.5. I didn't add the tag, as I didn't assume there would be much difference, but apparently, I was wrong.

Comment: @RickJames if you post it as an answer, it might help others too. Many who have started with MySQL probably have not checked the new features of MariaDB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MariaDB 10.3 has `GROUP_CONCAT(... LIMIT )`  (https://mariadb.com/kb/en/group_concat/)  `OFFSET` works, too.

MySQL 8.0 does not yet have `LIMIT`.  See bugs 82616 (2016), 71467, 62186, 30098, 12544 (2005) in bugs.mysql.com

Answer (score 1):

```sql
WITH cte AS ( SELECT *, DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY rank DESC) drnk
              FROM t1 )
SELECT id,
       GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(val,'|',rank) ORDER BY rank DESC SEPARATOR ',') 
FROM cte
WHERE drnk <= 2
GROUP BY id;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=ce501d92ef88b63bca30705037d19633

Comment: it doesn't work unles `rank` column is unique. `DENSE_RANK()` value is not unique. If `rank` is the same within a group, `DENSE_RAN()` remains `1`. We need a function like `ROW_NUMBER` for `WHERE drnk <= 2`. Of course, it was my mistake not to clarify `rank` column is not unique within a group, though it wasn't unique in the sample data.

Comment: @Googlebot *it doesn't work unles rank column is unique. DENSE_RANK() value is not unique.* If you want to limit rows included, not distinct `rank`, then you must expand sorting criteria which must provide rows uniqueness. Or alternatively you may agree to obtain indefinite row from possible duplicates by `rank`. For this you must replace `DENSE_RANK` with `ROW_NUMBER` and, maybe, expand sorting expression in the window definition. For example it can be `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY rank DESC, val ASC) drnk` (if `(rank,val)` provides the row uniqueness this is enough).

Comment: This solution requires MySQL 8.0 or MariaDB 10.2.